# Reporting of amortization expenses to FTB California

Tags: taxes, expenses, california, corporation, amortization

I have registered a corporation in Californa. So far, there have only been start up costs and no income. I  have lodged a Form 1120 with IRS and amortized the expenses over 60 months. Do I report the deduction also on the California return - form 100? If so, where do I show it? Do I also need to lodge a form 3885?

Answer (score 1):

California treatment of startup costs conforms to the Federal treatment, according to the [FTB Pub. 984](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/misc/984.pdf). So the deduction should appear on your Form 100 similarly to the way it appears on the IRS Form 1120, and you should attach the form 3885. Depreciation and amortization charges go on line 6 of form 100.

I suggest you get a California licensed tax adviser (EA/CPA licensed in California), or at least a certified tax preparer (CRTP in California) to help you with this. Corporate returns are not a "DIY" thing for most parts, especially C-Coprs.